# Can't use await

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I'm new to coding Discord bots in Python with the Nextcord library.

I ran into an issue with creating a transcript for a ticket.

The interaction to close the ticket failed due to what Python thinks is an issue.

Here is what my terminal said was the issue:

`line 52, in close_ticket messages = await interaction.channel.history(limit=None, oldest_first=True).flatten`

> TypeError: object method can't be used in 'await' expression Here is
> my code:

```
@nextcord.ui.button(
        label="Close Ticket", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id="ticket_settings:red"
    )
    async def close_ticket(self, button:nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        messages = await interaction.channel.history(limit=None, oldest_first=True).flatten
        contents = [message.content for message in messages]
        final = ""
        for msg in contents:
            msg = msg + "\n"
            fianl = final + msg
        with open('transcript.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(final)
        await interaction.response.send_message("Ticket is being closed.")
        await interaction.channel.delete()
        await interaction.user.send(f"Ticket closed in {interaction.channel.mention}. Here is the transcript.", file=nextcord.File(r'transcript.txt'))
        os.remove("transcript.txt")
```

Comment: https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.PartialMessageable.history

Answer (score 0):

`flatten` is a **method** ([see this](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.AsyncIterator.flatten)), you need to call it to use it in an await expression by adding `()` at the end.

To fix your issue, change this line:

```
messages = await interaction.channel.history(limit=None, oldest_first=True).flatten
```

Into this line:

```
messages = await interaction.channel.history(limit=None, oldest_first=True).flatten()
```

Off topic to your issue, but there's also a small typo in your code:

```
fianl = final + msg
```